# Quarkus alternative for spring @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)

Tags: java, spring, quarkus, scheduling

I tried implementing this `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)` by importing `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled` class, it gave following error on build:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid @Scheduled method 'monitorRoutesProcessing': 'fixedDelay' not supported

Is there any way to implement a scheduler with a fixed delay in Quarkus?
I understand we can implement a fixed rate using @every

Comment: Use `@io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled` as described https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler-reference

Answer (score 1):

The Quarkus equivalent is @io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled. Here's an example from [the official guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler):

```
package org.acme.scheduler;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import io.quarkus.scheduler.Scheduled;
import io.quarkus.scheduler.ScheduledExecution;

@ApplicationScoped              
public class CounterBean {

    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public int get() {  
        return counter.get();
    }

    @Scheduled(every="10s")     
    void increment() {
        counter.incrementAndGet(); 
    }

    @Scheduled(cron="0 15 10 * * ?") 
    void cronJob(ScheduledExecution execution) {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println(execution.getScheduledFireTime());
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "{cron.expr}") 
    void cronJobWithExpressionInConfig() {
       counter.incrementAndGet();
       System.out.println("Cron expression configured in application.properties");
    }
}
```

See also [the reference guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler-reference) for more information